# Date format in Backbone.js

Tags: date, backbone.js

I want to display current Date in this format"Monday,April,14,2014".I searched but couldn't get any proper link .It should be using backbone.Modal.extend .

Answer (score 1):

BackboneJS not responsible for date formatting. Make your own methods or use library like momentJS.

Comment: Thanks for idea..I have create own method for date.

Answer (score 0):

From the Backbone.js website: `Backbone.js gives structure to web applications by providing models with key-value binding and custom events, collections with a rich API of enumerable functions, views with declarative event handling, and connects it all to your existing API over a RESTful JSON interface.`

Having said that, backbone has nothing to do with parsing/displaying dates. If you want to parse dates and display it in a more human friendly way, you have to write it yourself or use some other library like http://momentjs.com/.

Please also see [https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global%5fObjects/Date) for documentation about the JavaScript `Date` object.